# Transposing dict of dataframes to single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, transpose

I have a `dict` data structure that contains a number of dataframes of feature importances. The `key` in each dict is a classifier name, while the `value` is a `pandas` dataframe containing the values, like so:

```
for k,v in clf_importances.items():
    print('Key: {} | Value: {}'.format(type(k),type(v)))
```

yields:

```
Key: <class 'str'> | Value: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Key: <class 'str'> | Value: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Key: <class 'str'> | Value: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Key: <class 'str'> | Value: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Key: <class 'str'> | Value: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Key: <class 'str'> | Value: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Printing out the full `key, value` pair looks like:

```
Key: ExtraTreesClassifier | Value:     Feature Importance Dataset Feature
5             0.083201           PAY_0
0             0.068004       LIMIT_BAL
4             0.067210             AGE
6             0.056047           PAY_2
11            0.050106       BILL_AMT1
22            0.046736        PAY_AMT6
12            0.045764       BILL_AMT2
13            0.045250       BILL_AMT3
16            0.044548       BILL_AMT6
15            0.043899       BILL_AMT5
21            0.043879        PAY_AMT5
17            0.043784        PAY_AMT1
14            0.043034       BILL_AMT4
19            0.042971        PAY_AMT3
20            0.041703        PAY_AMT4
18            0.041612        PAY_AMT2
7             0.039387           PAY_3
2             0.031250       EDUCATION
10            0.030024           PAY_6
8             0.027824           PAY_4
9             0.027166           PAY_5
3             0.025237        MARRIAGE
1             0.011363             SEX
Key: ExtraTreeClassifier | Value:     Feature Importance Dataset Feature
6             0.111777           PAY_2
4             0.066666             AGE
0             0.064150       LIMIT_BAL
5             0.060453           PAY_0
11            0.051967       BILL_AMT1
22            0.050377        PAY_AMT6
21            0.049969        PAY_AMT5
16            0.049288       BILL_AMT6
20            0.045553        PAY_AMT4
14            0.044610       BILL_AMT4
12            0.044503       BILL_AMT2
13            0.044042       BILL_AMT3
17            0.043317        PAY_AMT1
18            0.041014        PAY_AMT2
15            0.039467       BILL_AMT5
19            0.037373        PAY_AMT3
2             0.036266       EDUCATION
10            0.026815           PAY_6
9             0.025599           PAY_5
3             0.024912        MARRIAGE
8             0.017125           PAY_4
7             0.014786           PAY_3
1             0.009970             SEX
Key: AdaBoostClassifier | Value:     Feature Importance Dataset Feature
11                0.18       BILL_AMT1
5                 0.10           PAY_0
18                0.08        PAY_AMT2
13                0.08       BILL_AMT3
0                 0.08       LIMIT_BAL
6                 0.06           PAY_2
4                 0.04             AGE
21                0.04        PAY_AMT5
12                0.04       BILL_AMT2
16                0.04       BILL_AMT6
17                0.04        PAY_AMT1
19                0.04        PAY_AMT3
7                 0.02           PAY_3
8                 0.02           PAY_4
9                 0.02           PAY_5
10                0.02           PAY_6
1                 0.02             SEX
3                 0.02        MARRIAGE
15                0.02       BILL_AMT5
2                 0.02       EDUCATION
20                0.02        PAY_AMT4
14                0.00       BILL_AMT4
22                0.00        PAY_AMT6
Key: DecisionTreeClassifier | Value:     Feature Importance Dataset Feature
5             0.158990           PAY_0
4             0.077252             AGE
11            0.066710       BILL_AMT1
19            0.062703        PAY_AMT3
0             0.054219       LIMIT_BAL
16            0.053095       BILL_AMT6
22            0.052342        PAY_AMT6
15            0.049213       BILL_AMT5
18            0.046958        PAY_AMT2
13            0.046923       BILL_AMT3
12            0.045344       BILL_AMT2
20            0.044837        PAY_AMT4
21            0.044753        PAY_AMT5
17            0.038431        PAY_AMT1
14            0.038085       BILL_AMT4
6             0.035479           PAY_2
2             0.018172       EDUCATION
1             0.014922             SEX
3             0.014383        MARRIAGE
9             0.011636           PAY_5
10            0.010553           PAY_6
7             0.007770           PAY_3
8             0.007230           PAY_4
Key: GradientBoostingClassifier | Value:     Feature Importance Dataset Feature
5             0.607572           PAY_0
6             0.075356           PAY_2
11            0.042168       BILL_AMT1
0             0.036155       LIMIT_BAL
7             0.026805           PAY_3
19            0.024886        PAY_AMT3
9             0.024605           PAY_5
10            0.019280           PAY_6
18            0.017588        PAY_AMT2
17            0.016413        PAY_AMT1
8             0.014795           PAY_4
12            0.014004       BILL_AMT2
21            0.012856        PAY_AMT5
4             0.011481             AGE
13            0.009571       BILL_AMT3
15            0.007993       BILL_AMT5
2             0.007919       EDUCATION
20            0.007281        PAY_AMT4
16            0.007112       BILL_AMT6
22            0.006756        PAY_AMT6
14            0.005713       BILL_AMT4
1             0.001907             SEX
3             0.001781        MARRIAGE
Key: RandomForestClassifier | Value:     Feature Importance Dataset Feature
5             0.103434           PAY_0
4             0.067272             AGE
11            0.064569       BILL_AMT1
0             0.060646       LIMIT_BAL
15            0.052837       BILL_AMT5
12            0.052110       BILL_AMT2
13            0.050939       BILL_AMT3
17            0.050610        PAY_AMT1
14            0.050177       BILL_AMT4
16            0.049869       BILL_AMT6
20            0.046656        PAY_AMT4
18            0.046442        PAY_AMT2
22            0.046345        PAY_AMT6
21            0.045313        PAY_AMT5
19            0.044719        PAY_AMT3
6             0.035182           PAY_2
7             0.029101           PAY_3
9             0.028234           PAY_5
2             0.020276       EDUCATION
10            0.018902           PAY_6
3             0.012756        MARRIAGE
8             0.012076           PAY_4
1             0.011537             SEX
```

Ideally, I would get a dataframe that looks like (where the features are the feature names):

```
| Classifier | Feature_1 | Feature_2 | Feature_3 | Feature_4 | Feature_5 |  …n |
|:----------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---:|
|      A     |   0.062   |   0.298   |   0.000   |   0.215   |   0.000   | foo |
|      B     |   0.001   |   0.000   |   0.005   |   0.121   |   0.314   | foo |
|      C     |   0.005   |   0.054   |   0.015   |   0.000   |   0.587   | foo |
|      D     |   0.315   |   0.547   |   0.870   |   0.003   |   0.000   | foo |
|     …n     |    foo    |    foo    |    foo    |    foo    |    foo    | foo |
```

I have tried the following:
`pd.concat(list(clf_importances.values()), axis=1).T`

but that yields me:

```
                           0           1           2          3          4   \
Feature Importance  0.0680036   0.0113632   0.0312499  0.0252366  0.0672101   
Dataset Feature     LIMIT_BAL         SEX   EDUCATION   MARRIAGE        AGE   
Feature Importance  0.0641503  0.00996989   0.0362662  0.0249123  0.0666655   
Dataset Feature     LIMIT_BAL         SEX   EDUCATION   MARRIAGE        AGE   
Feature Importance       0.08        0.02        0.02       0.02       0.04   
Dataset Feature     LIMIT_BAL         SEX   EDUCATION   MARRIAGE        AGE   
Feature Importance  0.0542192   0.0149216   0.0181717  0.0143835  0.0772521   
Dataset Feature     LIMIT_BAL         SEX   EDUCATION   MARRIAGE        AGE   
Feature Importance  0.0361555  0.00190747  0.00791903  0.0017812  0.0114815   
Dataset Feature     LIMIT_BAL         SEX   EDUCATION   MARRIAGE        AGE   
Feature Importance  0.0606456   0.0115368   0.0202763  0.0127564  0.0672716   
Dataset Feature     LIMIT_BAL         SEX   EDUCATION   MARRIAGE        AGE   

                           5          6           7           8          9   \
Feature Importance  0.0832008  0.0560469   0.0393875   0.0278244  0.0271665   
Dataset Feature         PAY_0      PAY_2       PAY_3       PAY_4      PAY_5   
Feature Importance  0.0604535   0.111777   0.0147856   0.0171251  0.0255994   
Dataset Feature         PAY_0      PAY_2       PAY_3       PAY_4      PAY_5   
Feature Importance        0.1       0.06        0.02        0.02       0.02   
Dataset Feature         PAY_0      PAY_2       PAY_3       PAY_4      PAY_5   
Feature Importance    0.15899  0.0354792  0.00777045  0.00722966  0.0116362   
Dataset Feature         PAY_0      PAY_2       PAY_3       PAY_4      PAY_5   
Feature Importance   0.607572  0.0753564    0.026805   0.0147954  0.0246046   
Dataset Feature         PAY_0      PAY_2       PAY_3       PAY_4      PAY_5   
Feature Importance   0.103434  0.0351815   0.0291013   0.0120759  0.0282341   
Dataset Feature         PAY_0      PAY_2       PAY_3       PAY_4      PAY_5   

                    ...          13          14          15          16  \
Feature Importance  ...   0.0452499   0.0430338   0.0438993   0.0445483   
Dataset Feature     ...   BILL_AMT3   BILL_AMT4   BILL_AMT5   BILL_AMT6   
Feature Importance  ...   0.0440423   0.0446098   0.0394667    0.049288   
Dataset Feature     ...   BILL_AMT3   BILL_AMT4   BILL_AMT5   BILL_AMT6   
Feature Importance  ...        0.08           0        0.02        0.04   
Dataset Feature     ...   BILL_AMT3   BILL_AMT4   BILL_AMT5   BILL_AMT6   
Feature Importance  ...    0.046923   0.0380849   0.0492131   0.0530953   
Dataset Feature     ...   BILL_AMT3   BILL_AMT4   BILL_AMT5   BILL_AMT6   
Feature Importance  ...  0.00957132  0.00571326  0.00799286  0.00711225   
Dataset Feature     ...   BILL_AMT3   BILL_AMT4   BILL_AMT5   BILL_AMT6   
Feature Importance  ...   0.0509391   0.0501766   0.0528368   0.0498691   
Dataset Feature     ...   BILL_AMT3   BILL_AMT4   BILL_AMT5   BILL_AMT6   

                           17         18         19          20         21  \
Feature Importance  0.0437835   0.041612  0.0429715   0.0417033  0.0438786   
Dataset Feature      PAY_AMT1   PAY_AMT2   PAY_AMT3    PAY_AMT4   PAY_AMT5   
Feature Importance   0.043317  0.0410139  0.0373731   0.0455528  0.0499691   
Dataset Feature      PAY_AMT1   PAY_AMT2   PAY_AMT3    PAY_AMT4   PAY_AMT5   
Feature Importance       0.04       0.08       0.04        0.02       0.04   
Dataset Feature      PAY_AMT1   PAY_AMT2   PAY_AMT3    PAY_AMT4   PAY_AMT5   
Feature Importance  0.0384315  0.0469577  0.0627034   0.0448368  0.0447532   
Dataset Feature      PAY_AMT1   PAY_AMT2   PAY_AMT3    PAY_AMT4   PAY_AMT5   
Feature Importance  0.0164133   0.017588  0.0248857  0.00728105  0.0128564   
Dataset Feature      PAY_AMT1   PAY_AMT2   PAY_AMT3    PAY_AMT4   PAY_AMT5   
Feature Importance  0.0506096  0.0464419  0.0447186   0.0466556  0.0453134   
Dataset Feature      PAY_AMT1   PAY_AMT2   PAY_AMT3    PAY_AMT4   PAY_AMT5   

                            22  
Feature Importance    0.046736  
Dataset Feature       PAY_AMT6  
Feature Importance   0.0503769  
Dataset Feature       PAY_AMT6  
Feature Importance           0  
Dataset Feature       PAY_AMT6  
Feature Importance   0.0523415  
Dataset Feature       PAY_AMT6  
Feature Importance  0.00675569  
Dataset Feature       PAY_AMT6  
Feature Importance   0.0463446  
Dataset Feature       PAY_AMT6  

[12 rows x 23 columns]
```

How can I achieve the dataset I am looking for with the `dict` structures that I currently have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `concat` with `keys` option to label the classifiers, then `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
(pd.concat(clf_importances.values(), keys=clf_importances.keys())
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
   .set_index('Dataset Feature', append=True)
   ['Feature Importance']
   .unstack('Dataset Feature')
)
```

Output:

```
Dataset Feature            AGE  BILL_AMT1  BILL_AMT2  BILL_AMT3  BILL_AMT4 ...
ExtraTreeClassifier   0.066666   0.051967   0.044503   0.044042   0.044610 ...
ExtraTreesClassifier  0.067210   0.050106   0.045764   0.045250   0.043034 ...
...
```

Comment: You are a life saver!! Thank you!!